# Java OutofMemoryException while appending large String using StringBuilder/StringWriter/String.format()

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve a programming problem in which I'm dealing with a large-sized String I tried using String, StringBuilder but got OutOfMermoryException Java Heap Space while appending the string. 
when tried with StringWriter with String.format() it takes forever to run the program(more than 15mins).

Please suggest what can be used when the length of String is 736778906400L I've attached the code(git-repo)

- https://github.com/surprogrammer/Practice/blob/master/RepeatedString.java

Comment: Why do you need to build such a huge string ? Is there any alternative ? File ?

Comment: This is 100% normal so what do you expect ?

Comment: That String's length is 686 Gigabyte (Gibibyte, technically) if you use a single byte per character (which is possible in newer JDK's). You're only going to be able to keep that in memory if you have at least that much memory. But you're doing manipulation on it, so you need a lot more memory to hold the copies. Come up with a different approach that doesn't require keeping the whole string in memory at once.

Comment: use Files or split and try with multi Threads

Comment: @HiteshKumar, using multiple threads does not, in fact, magically give you more RAM.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt this is a part of a programming challenge. Can you please suggest an approach where I can release memory without losing data in my String

Comment: Could you please edit the question to include the text of the challenge? Or paraphrase it? Please.

Comment: I am not sure why this question is being downvoted? Are those people who downvoted think that this is a trivial problem? Or is the problem duplicated? Or is the problem not worthy enough to be resolved? I m curious

Comment: I assume this is your challenge: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/repeated-string/problem
The point there is that you should not create a single string with the repeated characters, but that you find a way of counting the letter a in a "virtual" infinite string without constructing it. Asking how to do that, is too broad for a StackOverflow question

Answer (score 0):

If you need to just count character in repeated string - count it:

```
   static long repeatedString(String s, long n) {
        final char charToCheck='a';
        if (s.indexOf(charToCheck)>=1) {
            return s.chars()
                    .filter(value -> value == (int)charToCheck)
                    .count()*n;
        } else
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: infiniteString(String strInput, Long n) will get called before repeatedString() and it throws OOM exception while appending on line 52  stringBuilder.append( strInput);

Comment: It depends on your issue. If you need to just count character entry in string in any way - so you don't need to create large string. It is enough to use multiplication. If your issue is to work with large string in any case - it is not your solution